# create a new instance of group of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am beginner in jQuery and asp.net. I created a simple chat application using SignalR, the design of which you can find here   **[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/utoyej/1/edit)**

How can I create a new instance of that *chat design* whenever a user has been call by other user while he/she were in chat from before with other user. Here I think I can convert it to User Control. but I dont want to have same `Id`'s which I am using for other chat design and those generated instances should work differently, I mean if `userA` calls `userB` and at the same time `userC` calls `userB` then they must be created in such a way that they must be unique in handling there own calls (just like FB Chat).

The another issue may arise after successfully creating a new instance is that they might not be get attached to the jQuery functions and server side code automatically. If so, anyway to solve this too?

Before asking here I searched alot (maybe I dont know the exact keyword to search for).

**EDIT**: Many jQuery developers suggested me to go with *Knockout.js* or *Backbone.js* or simple jQuery. But I think there is some simple way to achieve this using ASP.NET functions like *User Control* or *HTTP Handlers* (or something else). About which I dont know anything. So, please suggest me which concept to opt for ? and please give detailed explanation(if possible with simple example).

jquery related answers are also welcome.

**Single Instance**

[image]

**Multiple Instances**

[image]

Comment: That's a lengthy request.  What you should look into is using SignalR for a chat application. (Also, what have you tried)

Comment: @Hexxagonal I completed the chat application, now I want to have this feature. Hey I created using signalr itself. (I edited my post)

Comment: @Hexxagonal how to achieve this using SignalR? Can you please share any links or ideas which you think might help me?

Comment: Right now I am referring this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86(v=vs.100).aspx). If you got any idea please share :)

Comment: I would suggest using a client side technology as there is no big reason here to do a round trip to server when using signalR to send message to client for new chat request. You can use signalR to even update the server for how many chat windows are open and their minimum data required to initiate those same chat requests if a user  accidently closes browser and comes back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JQuery to populate or popup new instance of chat but change your ids using jquery. I would suggest have all your styling and ids done according to a parent container so you can easily grap the parent, duplicate it and change the IDs or content.

I would keep a non filled chat window with ID's like "updateme1" updateme2 etc and then once i get it as a template i will replace all ids one by one with relevant content.

You are doing it right and i dont think its signalR that you need to look into. SignalR would be able to help you pass on specific parameters like "requirechatwindow=true or false" based on if this person is in chat with current person but you can always do this on client as well by going through current open chat sessions. If current chat session does not contain a chat between A and B then open new window with new ID and put a data-from= A and data-to=B as a palceholder so you know this chat is between A and B etc

Hope this helps

**UPDATED Fiddle and technique**

Here is the fix on [Your fiddle edited to show creation and multiple ids](http://jsbin.com/utoyej/85/edit) I had to adjust some of your css to view the boxes in different location

[Updated the code with some comments](http://jsbin.com/utoyej/85/edit)

The technique is simple:

1. You create a html template on your page might be in a hidden region
2. You then use that to create new element in a container and have a handle to pickup this element for example in my code the currentid is my handle but i know the container name so i will only pickup template populated within the actual container to avoid conflict with template itself.
3. Assign a new id and then you can use any events or any speacial objects on there.
4. You can then pickup new elements from the new id or any other handle you might have inside them. For example i have just added a click even on it with confirm to hide it.

   ```
   $('#doubleme').click(function(){    
       var currentid = $("#chattemplate .chat-outline").attr('data-tid');     
       var newid = parseInt(currentid,10) + 1;
       $("#chatcontainers").append($("#chattemplate").html());    
       $("#chatcontainers .chat-outline").attr('id',"id"+newid); 
       $("#chattemplate .chat-outline").attr('data-tid',newid);  
   });
   ```

You only need these five lines of code actually and if you go to fiddle i have commented all of them but they are easy to understand. I am using selectors used in fiddle but these can be further optimised with attributes like `data-handle-for` or whatever name you can give.

If you are considering this for SignalR then within your hub response of new request you can call the intiate chat window which can setup everything on the client. Any subsequent messages using that data handle can be updated within this new chat window.

For example i assume you create a new group called "chatwindow7" and "chatwindow8" which makes its round trip in your send method and so on get broadcast to only user with this group. Then each user might have multiple windows open but you only need to pickup chatwindow7 for messages with that data handle and update it and so on.

If you are using one-to-one chat users only then you can use connection id as well which means all messages broadcasted will have both sender and reciever (by deafault) connection ID and you only need to pickup the window with connection id handle and update its list of messages or whatever.

Comment: use live to get events on dynamically created boxes.

Comment: I think you mean `on`, as `live` has been deprecated. please provide a simple example, that would be really helpful for me to understand.. (as I am new to jQuery)

Comment: You are lucky to have the bounty which I saw when it was going to be expired in 5 mins.. :D Still I haven't checked your code but as the fiddle was working.. so I gave the points to you.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to replace the id attributes with class attributes.

```
<div id="chat-outline">
    ...
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="chat-outline">
    ...
</div>
```

And update your CSS appropriately.

```
.chat-outline
{
    background-color: gray;
    ....
}
```

Then use a text/template tag to make it available to jQuery.

```
<script type="text/template" id="chat-template">
    <div class="chat-outline">
        ...
    </div>
</script>
```

Note that because browsers ignore script types they don't recognise, this will be ignored  by the html rendering engine, but as it has an id, it will be visible to jQuery, and can be accessed thus:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var chatTemplate = $('#chat-template').html();
        $('#container').append(chatTemplate);  // First instance
        $('#container').append(chatTemplate);  // Second instance
        $('#container').append(chatTemplate);  // Third instance
    });
</script>
```

Of course, if your code needs an id attribute as a handle for a chat instance, you can create a function that creates the chat-instance html given an id. In this case I'll use underscore to provide random-id, template, and iteration functions, but it is easy to use another library, or write your own.

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="chat-template">
    <div class="chat-outline" id="<%= id %>">
        ...
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var createChatInstance(idstring) {
        return _.template($('#chat-template').html(), { id: idstring });
    }

    $(function() {
        var chatTemplate = $('#chat-template').html();
        // Create an array of 3 unique ids by which chat instances will be accessed.
        var chatIds = [_.uniqueId('chat-outline'), 
                       _.uniqueId('chat-outline'), 
                       _.uniqueId('chat-outline')];
        _.each(chatIds, function(chatId) {
            $('#container').append(createChatInstance(chatId));
        });
        // You now have an array of 3 unique ids matching 3 divs.
        // You can access individual sub-divs via descendent class matching from the id
        // thus: $('#' + chatIds[n] + ' .chat-message').keyup(...code handling event...);

    });
</script>
```

At this point, if you want to take the architecture further, you really do need to consider investigating something like backbone.js.

Hope this helps.